# Points are removable for weakly differentiable functions

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

If $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^N$ is an open set and $N \ge 2$, then any point $a \in \Omega$ is removable for weakly differentiable maps: for each function $u \in W^{1, 1} (\Omega \setminus \{a\})$, then $u \in W^{1, 1} (\Omega)$.

This can be proved by using the definition of weak derivative by testing a directional derivative of $u$ against a smooth function and by applying Fubini theorem to integrate by parts along every straight line that does not contain the point $a$. Since we have assumed that $N \ge 2$, almost every straight line parallel to a fixed direction does not contain $a$ and the property can be proved.

This removability property is useful to construct examples of nonsmooth weakly differentiable functions: this property implies that if $u \in C^1 (\Omega \setminus \{a\}) \cap L^1 (\Omega)$ and $D u \in L^1 (\Omega)$, then $u \in W^{1, 1} (\Omega)$. This is very handy in elementary exercises and in delicate proofs on Sobolev spaces.

I am searching for this statement and its proof in the literature.

I could not find it in Adams, Brezis, Willem and Ziemer’s books.
I have found a proof of a more general statement, when the set $\{a\}$ is replaced by a negligible set for the Hausdorff measure $\mathcal{H}^{N - 1}$ (Maz'ya, *Sobolev spaces*, 2009, theorem 1.1.18, who gives credits to Väisälä and Reshetnyak), but I am still searching for a reference covering the elementary case of removing points.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this is equivalent to the statement "points have zero capacity".  I don't have a reference for you but this might help your searching.

Comment: Removability of points follows from the fact that points have null capacity, _once_ you know that $u \in L^{N/(N - 1)} (\Omega)$ (which follows from the Gagliardo-Nirenberg-Sobolev embedding theorem, that you then need to prove). I have the impression that null capacity of a set is related to the approximability by functions that vanish on that set.